# Android generating release apk, getting failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease'

Tags: android, release

I'm trying to build my release apk and Android Stdio gives me error. I cleaned and built the project multiple times but the error is still there. Multidex is disabled in build.gradle file and I also use Proguard to shrink the code.

When I generating release apk, I'm getting error like this. I don't know what is the problem. I have searched in stackoverflow but no solution anywhere.

```
Note: there were 30 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
  You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
  (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)

Warning: there were 1160 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 49 unresolved references to program class members.
     Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
     You may need to recompile the code.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
     You probably need to update the library versions.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
... 20 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:54)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:254)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:225)


BUİLD FAILED

Total time: 31.156 secs
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have minify enabled in your proguard you should use

```
-ignorewarnings
```

in proguard rules file

hopefully, it helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21666886)

Comment: I did not provide any link! and the entire answer is to just add this line of code to a file which I have specified. what could I do more than this?

Comment: You are right (now)... Sorry, must have been a mistake. I don't know if I can take this back but I have seen most reviewers flagged this as *looks ok*, so it won't be deleted anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing `compileSdkVersion` in your app-level gradle. A newer to an old version depending on what SDK you're using.

Also make sure `minifyEnabled` is set to *false*.